# error when compile Hive mvn clean package -Pdist

Tags: maven, hive

during compile Hive on ubuntu I run this command.

```
    $ git clone https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hive.git
    $ cd hive
    $ mvn clean package -Pdist
```

then i get this Error

```
    [INFO] Reactor Summary:
    [INFO]
    [INFO] Hive .............................................. SUCCESS [5.461s]
    [INFO] Hive Shims Common ................................. SUCCESS [10.078s]
    [INFO] Hive Shims 0.23 ................................... SUCCESS [5.099s]
    [INFO] Hive Shims Scheduler .............................. SUCCESS [1.569s]
    [INFO] Hive Shims ........................................ SUCCESS [0.728s]
    [INFO] Hive Storage API .................................. SUCCESS [3.465s]
    [INFO] Hive Common ....................................... SUCCESS [1:08.210s]
    [INFO] Hive Serde ........................................ SUCCESS [1:34.094s]
    [INFO] Hive Metastore .................................... SUCCESS [2:48.406s]
    [INFO] Hive Ant Utilities ................................ SUCCESS [0.606s]
    [INFO] Hive Llap Client .................................. SUCCESS [2.148s]
    [INFO] Spark Remote Client ............................... SUCCESS [29.152s]
    [INFO] Hive Query Language ............................... FAILURE [1:41.379s]
    [INFO] Hive Service ...................................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] Hive Accumulo Handler ............................. SKIPPED
```

...

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project hive-exec: Compilation failure
```

How do i can fix this error help me please!

Comment: Please post the output of "mvn clean -X", as shown in the error. Unknown error doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: the out put is bigger than I can post it here how can i send it for you

Comment: I think you should be able to use http://pastebin.com to post the output and then post the link here.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0i6Z6xv1 error link

Comment: this is main error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Answer (score 1):

Maven compiler plugin is going out of memory. You can allocate it more memory bu making following changes to compiler plugin configuration in the root pom.xml.

It's at **line 738**

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.7</source>
    <target>1.7</target>
    <jvmArgs>-Xmx2048m -Xms512m</jvmArgs><!--increasing memory-->
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I have set it to 2GB, that may be overkill but try it first.
Also try running build without tests, using following command.

```
mvn clean package -Pdist -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

`-Dmaven.test.skip` will skip running the test cases and will produce the build results faster.

Answer (score 0):

Build success when i didn't specify the Hadoop Version and skipped the test cases using this command :

mvn clean package -DskipTests